# How to use curly brace escaping for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

According to [this link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Oracle_10g_escaping), I should be able to use curly braces to escape an entire variable string. My understanding is that Oracle (10g or later -- I've been told we use 11g) should treat this (sanitized) SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = 'Sam'
```

the same as it treats this one:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = '{Sam}'
```

I tried it as a sanity check before trying strings that would actually need escaping, and it didn't work. The top query returns data, but the bottom doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Egor's answer is the correct one. The `q` sets up a "quoted literal". The Oracle 10 docs explain this a lot clearer than the Oracle 11 docs. The Oracle 10 string literal documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617).

Comment: Yeah, that does clear it up a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = q'{Sam}'
```