# EF6 throws “Input string was not in a correct format” exception with escaped char

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, oracle12c, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have this code that works in all cases except if there is a `?` or `=` sign inside `{}`

```
 var db = new MyContext();
 var fullSql =
 @"select /*+ PARALLEL(6) */ id 
    from table1 ( contains(sometext,' ( {?}xxx ) ') > 0 ) 
    and some_field = :someParam order by xxx desc fetch next 10 rows only ";
var sqlParams = new List<object>();
sqlParams.Add(0);
var ids = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(fullSql, sqlParams.ToArray()).ToList();
```

If I remove {?} it works, if I hardcode `someParam` it also works. If not it throughs `Input string was not in a correct format`

Edit: seems like EF treats things inside Curly Brackets as parameters

Answer (score 1):

Yea, as you mentioned in the comments, the solution is to replace all `{` with `{{`. And all `}` with `}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a  "q" infront of your string, to make it literal

thus: from table1 ( contains(sometext,q' ( {?}xxx ) ') > 0 )

See this question: [How to use curly brace escaping for Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167883/how-to-use-curly-brace-escaping-for-oracle)

Comment: it's not the Oracle, it's EF that treats {?} as a parameter and looks for it in `sqlParams`

Comment: ok the solution is to escape with {{}} but ONLY if there is sqlParams present. damn...